# ¿Cómo estilizo lo que quedo del salto de página para que quede bien en dompdf?

Tags: php, dompdf

Tengo una situación, he enviado una tabla a *pdf* con *dompdf*, al momento de hacer el salto de página lo hace perfecto, pero en la página siguiente lo que resta de la tabla se monta sobre el encabezado, he tratado solventarlo, pero tengo otros proyectos y a este le he estado dedicando tiempo de más.

Adjunto el código y las imágenes de como queda:

```
<?php include_once "../conf/Configuracion.php"; ob_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<title>cecofal.com Tu solucion cooperativa</title>

<head>
  <style>
    /** Establezca los márgenes de la página en 0, por lo que el pie de página y el encabezado puede ser de altura   y     anchura completas. **/
    
    @page {
      margin: 0cm 0cm;
    }
    /** Defina ahora los márgenes reales de cada página en el PDF **/
    
    body {
      margin-top: 3cm;
      margin-left: 2cm;
      margin-right: 2cm;
      margin-bottom: 2cm;
    }
    /** Definir las reglas del encabezado **/
    
    header {
      position: fixed;
      top: 2cm;
      left: 2cm;
      right: 2cm;
      height: 3cm;
    }
    /** Definir las reglas del pie de página **/
    
    footer {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 2cm;
      left: 2cm;
      right: 2cm;
      height: 2cm;
    }
    
    main {
      margin-top: 5cm;
      margin-left: 0cm;
      margin-right: 0cm;
      margin-bottom: 2cm;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!---------- Cabecera  Cabecera  Cabecera  Cabecera  Cabecera  Cabecera  Cabecera ---------------------->
  <header>
    <div id="photo" style="text-align: center">
      <img src="../imagenes/72.png" alt="" width="150" style="vertical-align:middle" />
      <h4 style="float:right;">
        Comprobante N#:
        <?php 
               $peticion = $db->query("SELECT * FROM diario WHERE comprobante='".$_GET['comprobamte']."'"); 
               $columna = $peticion->fetch_assoc(); 
         $item = array('comprobante' => $columna['comprobante'], 'fechafac'=>$columna['fechafac'], 'concepto'=>$columna['      concepto'], 'desccripcion'=>$columna['descripcion'] ); 
               echo $item['comprobante'].' DE FECHA: '.date('d-m-Y',strtotime($item['fechafac']));?> </h4>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <font size="1"><strong>CONCEPTO:</strong>
        <?php echo $item['concepto']?>
      </font>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!---------- pie de pag  pie de pag  pie de pag  pie de pag  pie de pag  pie de pag  pie de pag   --------------------    -->
  <footer>
    <center>
      <table width="100%">
        <tbody>
          <?php $sentencia = $base_de_datos->query("SELECT * FROM diario WHERE comprobante='".$_GET['comprobamte']."'  "); 
                $productos = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); ?>
          <?php $saldo = 0; $sumhaber= 0; $sumdebe = 0; 
                foreach($productos as $producto){
                  $_SESSION['departamento'] = $producto->departamento;
                  $_SESSION['comprobante']= $producto->comprobante;
                  $sumhaber = $producto->haber + $sumhaber;
                  $sumdebe = $producto->debe + $sumdebe;
                  $_SESSION['sumhaber']=$sumhaber;
                  $_SESSION['sumadebe']= $sumdebe; }
                  ?>
          <tr>
            <td width="50%"></td>
            <td width="30%" align="right">
              <font size="1"><strong>TOTAL COMPROBANTE</strong></font>
            </td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">
              <font size="1">
                <?php echo   number_format($_SESSION['sumadebe'],2,",",".")?> </font>
            </td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">
              <font size="1">
                <?php echo  number_format($_SESSION['sumhaber'],2,",",".") ?> </font>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <table width="100%" style="@media print{ border: 1px solid #000;  border-radius: 10px;  }  ">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" style="border: black 1px solid;">
              <font size="1">BANCO</font>
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="border: black 1px solid;">
              <font size="1">CUENTA</font>
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="border: black 1px solid;">
              <font size="1">TIPO TRANSACCION</font>
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="border: black 1px solid;">
              <font size="1">SERVICIO</font>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="center">
            <td style="border: black 1px solid;">
              <font size="1">
                <?php  $peticion2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM   diario     WHERE comprobante='".$_GET['comprobamte']."' AND definicion='111' and mayor='201'");
                    $columna2 = $peticion2->fetch_assoc(); 
              $item2 = array('banco' => $columna2['banco'], 'n_cuenta_ban'=>$columna2['n_cuenta_ban'], 'tipo_trasn_p'=>  $    columna2['tipo_trasn_p'] ); 
      
                    echo $item2['banco']?>
              </font>
            </td>
            <td style="border: black 1px solid;">
              <font size="1">
                <?php echo $item2['n_cuenta_ban'] ?>
              </font>
            </td>
            <td style="border: black 1px solid;">
              <font size="1">
                <?php echo $item2['tipo_trasn_p'] ?>
              </font>
            </td>
            <td style="border: black 1px solid;">
              <font size="1">
                <?php if($_SESSION['departamento']=='6'){echo'      Servicio de Gas';} ?>
              </font>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" style="border: black 1px solid;">
              <font size="1">COMPROBANTE</font>
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="border: black 1px solid;">
              <font size="1">HECHO POR:</font>
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="border: black 1px solid;">
              <font size="1">CONTABILIDAD</font>
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="border: black 1px solid;">
              <font size="1">FECHA</font>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="center">
            <td style="border: black 1px solid;">
              <font size="1">
                <?php echo $_SESSION['comprobante']?>
              </font>
            </td>
            <td style="border: black 1px solid;" width="25%"></td>
            <td style="border: black 1px solid;" width="25%"></td>
            <td style="border: black 1px solid;" width="25%"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </center>
  </footer>
  <!---------- cuerpo de   cuerpo de   cuerpo de   cuerpo de   cuerpo de   cuerpo de   cuerpo de    --------------------    -->
  <main>
    <table width="100%">
      <?php $sentencia_diario = $base_de_datos->query("SELECT * FROM diario WHERE comprobante='".$_GET['comprobamte  ']."    '"); 
              $producto_diarios = $sentencia_diario->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); ?>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <center>
              <font size="1"><strong>Codigo</strong></font>
            </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center>
              <font size="1"><strong>Descripcion</strong></font>
            </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center>
              <font size="1"><strong>Debito</strong></font>
            </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center>
              <font size="1"><strong>Credito</strong></font>
            </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php foreach($producto_diarios as $producto_diario){ ?>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <font size="1">
              <?php echo $producto_diario->codigo.' - '. $producto_diario->cuenta ;?>
            </font>
          </td>
          <td>
            <font size="1">
              <?php echo $producto_diario->descripcion ?>
            </font>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <font size="1">
              <?php echo number_format($producto_diario->debe,2,",",".") ?>
            </font>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <font size="1">
              <?php echo number_format($producto_diario->haber,2,",",".") ?>
            </font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </center>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
<?php 
      $html = ob_get_clean();
      //echo $html;
      
      require_once "../dompdf/autoload.inc.php";
      // reference the Dompdf namespace
      use Dompdf\Dompdf;
      
      // instantiate and use the dompdf class
      $dompdf = new Dompdf();
      
      
      $options = $dompdf->getOptions();
      $options->set(array('isRemoteEnable'=> true));
      $dompdf->setOptions($options);
      
      $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
      
      $dompdf->setPaper('letter');
      
      $dompdf->render();
      
      $dompdf->stream("reporte.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));?>
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Amigos lo consegui luego de varios intentos y de leer mucho logre estilizar las hojas espero le sea de ayuda a los que tienen el mismo problema les dejo la etiqueta de style que use:

```
<style> 
    /** Establezca los márgenes de la página en 0, por lo que el pie de página y el encabezado puede ser de altura   y     anchura completas. **/ 
      @page {
        margin: 0cm 0cm;
      }
  
      /** Defina ahora los márgenes reales de cada página en el PDF **/
      body {
        margin-top: 3cm;
        margin-left: 2cm;
        margin-right: 2cm;
        margin-bottom: 2cm;
      }
  
      /** Definir las reglas del encabezado **/
      header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 2cm;
        left: 2cm;
        right: 2cm;
        height: 3cm;

      }
  
      /** Definir las reglas del pie de página **/
      footer {
        position: fixed; 
        bottom: 2cm; 
        left: 2cm; 
        right: 2cm;
        height: 2cm;
      }
      main {
        position: relative;
        top: 170px;
        left: 0cm;
        right: 0cm;
        margin-bottom: 2cm;
      } 
    </style>
```

Comment: Bro, como puedo contactarte, tengo un problema en generar una tabla ya que en un salto de pagina me borra una linea de una celda

Comment: Escribeme a mi corrreo ing.jhonnyjaimes@gmail.com